# Unexpected string.replace() result

Tags: javascript

Why does this fail? Should I (somehow) escape letter `i` — this doesn't fail with other characters.

```
titleCase("I'm a little tea pot");

// Prints:   "i'm A Little Tea Pot"
// Expected: "I'm A Little Tea Pot"

function titleCase(str) {
  return str.split(' ').map(function(each) {
    return each.toLowerCase().replace(each[0], each[0].toUpperCase());
  }).join(' ');
}
```

Comment: Chaining doesn't work like that -- when you issue `each.toLowerCase().replace(each[0], each[0].toUpperCase())`, `each[0]` is still the "old" `each`, not the result of `each.toLowerCase()`.

Comment: As a side note, you could achieve this using CSS if it's for display purposes only: `text-transform: capitalize`

Comment: It fails for any character at index 0; but 
`function titleCase(str) {
  return str.split(' ').map(function(each) {
    return each.toLowerCase().replace(each[0].toLowerCase(), each[0].toUpperCase());
  }).join(' ');`
}

should solve the issue.

Comment: @Curt that will only update UI but when you submit it to server, it will go in original (entered) format

Comment: @Rajesh Completely agree, hence why I stated for display purposes only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.toLowerCase()` is happening on the original value of `each`, so the `.replace()` may/will not give you the expected results.

If you split it out as a separate statement, it should work as expected:

```
function titleCase(str) {
    return str.split(' ').map(function(each) {
        each = each.toLowerCase();
        return each.replace(each[0], each[0].toUpperCase());
    }).join(' ');
}
```

As a slightly more efficient approach, it would also be better to move the `.toLowerCase()` to before the `.map()` call so it only needs to be called once, instead of once-per-word:

```
function titleCase(str) {
    str = str.toLowerCase();
    return str.split(' ').map(function(each) {
        return each.replace(each[0], each[0].toUpperCase());
    }).join(' ');
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that's it, thank you. I'll choose yours by 10 secs compared to @Rahul Patel's.

Answer (score 1):

For "I'm" part of string the uppercase "I" converted to lowercase "i" and trying to replace the lowercase "i" with uppercase 'I' which is not even exist in the string.

So modified your function in the beginning converted entire string in lowercase.

Please check below working snippet.

```js
console.log(titleCase("I'm a little tea pot"));

// Prints:   "i'm A Little Tea Pot"
// Expected: "I'm A Little Tea Pot"

function titleCase(str) {
  str = str.toLowerCase();
  return str.split(' ').map(function(each) {
    //console.log(each[0].toUpperCase());
    return each.toLowerCase().replace(each[0], each[0].toUpperCase());
  }).join(' ');
}
```

Comment: Yeah, you're right. Thanks. The `toLowerCase` inside loop is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

#### Array.map

```js
function titleCase(str) {  
  return str.split(' ').map(function(each) {
    return each.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + each.substring(1).toLowerCase();
  }).join(' ');
}

console.log(titleCase("I'm a little tea pot"));
```

#### Array.reduce

```js
function titleCase(str) {  
  return str.split(' ').reduce(function(p,c) {
    return p + " " + toTitle(c);
  });
}

function toTitle(str){
  return str.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str.substring(1).toLowerCase();
}

console.log(titleCase("I'm a little tea pot"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Run the following snippet and look at the output.

```js
var each ="I'm";

console.log(`Change ${each[0]} to ${each[0].toUpperCase()} in ${each.toLowerCase()}`);
console.log('Result:', each.toLowerCase().replace(each[0], each[0].toUpperCase()));
```

You should see that the char to search is a capital "I" but the first char in the string is a lower case "i".

```js
function titleCase(str) {
  return str.toLowerCase().split(' ').map(function(each) {
    return each.replace(each[0], each[0].toUpperCase());
  }).join(' ');
}

console.log(titleCase("I\'m a little tea pot"));

// Prints:   "i'm A Little Tea Pot"
// Expected: "I'm A Little Tea Pot"
```

Comment: Thank you but it's kinda duplicate of @Rahul Patel's.

Answer (score 0):

It is simple.

```
replace(each[0], each[0].toUpperCase());
```

will only replace `lowerCase` items, and `I` is not `lowercase` since `each[0]` being not yet replaced.

For other words in the sentence, their first character is lowercase, so they stay lowercase after `lowercase()` is called on `each`.

Comment: I'm afraid it's not that simple. I need to make sure everything is lowercase and first letter uppercase.

Comment: @JonatasWalker Ohh, I thought you only want to know why is it failing. For a solution, you can simply replace that `.toLowerCase()` call on `each`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use regular expression for this.

```
function titleCase(str) {
 return str.replace(/(?:^|\s)\w/g, function(match) {
        return match.toUpperCase();
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I need to make sure only first letter is uppercase.

Comment: This will make first letter of each word uppercase.

Comment: In your original code if you just remove .toLowerCase() after each it will work fine. i.e replace each.toLowerCase().replace(....) with each.replace(....)

Comment: you forgot to lowerCase the rest of the word, and I'd rather use `\S` than `\w` to also include characters from foreign languages. `str.toLowerCase().replace(/(?:^|\s)\S/g, ...)`

Answer (score 0):

[`toLowerCase`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase) returns a new string, it does not update the value of `each`. So when `"I'm"` is assigned to `each` what you are effectively getting is:

```
"i'm".replace("I", "I".toUpperCase());
```

`"I"` is not in the string `"i'm"`, so nothing is replaced.

Instead of splitting the string, running replace on each token and joining it, I would instead do it with a single `replace` with [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) and a [replacement function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter):

```
function titleCase (str) {
  var upper = function (wholeMatch, before, firstLetter) {
      return before + firstLetter.toUpperCase();
    };
  return (str.toLowerCase()).replace(/(^\s*|\s+)(.)/g, upper);
}

titleCase("I'm a little tEa pot");
// "I'm A Little Tea Pot"

titleCase("   I'm a little tEa pot");
// "   I'm A Little Tea Pot"

titleCase(" I'm a little    tEa pot");
" I'm A Little    Tea Pot"
```

`/(^\s*|\s+)(.)/g` finds either the start of the string (with optional white-space) or white-space followed by any single character. The `upper` function then uppercases the character and returns any captured white-space and that upper case character to act as the replacement.